# Cauchy's function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, functional-equations

*An exercise in Real and Complex analysis (exercise 18, page 195,chapter 9)*

> Show that if a function $f$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ satisfies
>
> \begin{equation*}
> f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)
> \end{equation*}
>
> and if $f$ possesses Lebesgue measure, then $f$ is continuous.

I can't do this question. Any advice or hints would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you please include what you have tried? That way, it is easier for other people to help you.

Comment: Notice that $f(2x)=2f(x) , f(3x)=3f(x) ,f(nx)=nf(x)$

Comment: I know that $f(I)$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ for each open interval $I$ or $f$ is continuous. It's not too hard, but this new statement (new for me) seems much stronger.

Comment: You need the following theorem:                                                                     **Lusin's Theorem:** Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a nonnegative, measurable function. Suppose $ϵ>0$. Then $∃$ a compact set $K\subset [0,1]$ such that $m(K)>1−ϵ$ ($K$ fills out most of $[0,1]$), and a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x∈K$.

Comment: @Hrodelbert: I know that too, but I couldn't apply it to prove my exercise.